# Difference from Twisted and Tornado?

Tags: comet, twisted, server-push, tornado

I need to create a simple browser chat using a Comet webserver.

So I have found Twisted and Tornado.

What is the difference ?

Comment: Perhaps the respective project websites explain something about the differences.  I'm not sure this is a good question for stackoverflow, since it seems to indicate about zero effort using existing resources to come up with an answer, and it's so extremely broad that an answer could easily be a dozen pages long.

Perhaps you should do a little bit of research on your own and then try a more specific question.

Answer (score 4):

Tornado is a web server. Twisted is an event-based framework that can handle [many more protocols](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/upgrades/2.0/split.html), as well as non-network services such as GUIs.

Comment: tornado is more than a web server